# How to display the cards in proper format

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4

I have created a group of cards in angular using a for loop like this:

```
    <div class="row">
      <div *ngFor="let dev_data of data" class="col-3">
          <div class="card shadow">
              <div class="card-body">
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here for one row there will be 4 cards,

In the bigger screen's the data inside the cards are being displayed properly, but when I open my application in mobile or ipad the cards are completely going out:

like this:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap has predefined classes that help in displaying contents in responsive way. By using the class "col-3" you are saying bootstrap to display the contents to take 3 columns(Total of 12 Columns in Bootstrap) of the view no matter the display size.
So you can try like below code to instruct bootstrap to display content for 3 columns in md(Medium screen) and lg(Large Screen) and sm(Small Screen) to take the full width.

```
<div class="row">
      <div *ngFor="let dev_data of data" class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
          <div class="card shadow">
              <div class="card-body">
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

[Bootstrap Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options)

[image]